# zipruby が入りません。（Ruby 1.9.3 mingw32 に zipruby 0.3.6）

Tags: ruby

### 発生している問題

ネットに出ている情報をいろいろ試してみましたが、zipruby が入りません。
１．`gem install zipruby`
ネットに出ている通り

```
C:\>gem install zipruby 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
ERROR:  Error installing zipruby: 
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. 

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
checking for zlib.h... no 
*** extconf.rb failed *** 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more 
details.  You may need configuration options. 

Provided configuration options: 
        --with-opt-dir 
        --without-opt-dir 
        --with-opt-include 
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include 
        --with-opt-lib 
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib 
        --with-make-prog 
        --without-make-prog 
        --srcdir=. 
        --curdir 
        --ruby=C:/Ruby/bin/ruby 

I am an extreme newbie to building C extensions, so my Googling for 
details on the zlib library did not do me much good.  Any suggestions 
for how to proceed?
```

が出力されます。

２．`gem install zipruby1.9 --platform mswin32`
ネットで紹介されている方法ですが、

```
C:\>gem install zipruby1.9 --platform mswin32
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'zipruby1.9' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR: Possible alternatives: zipruby1.9
```

となり入りません。

３．`zlib.h` を入れて(zlib-1.2.3-lib.zip) `gem install zipruby`

```
C:\>gem install zipruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing zipruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170410-2492-i5v1a8.rb extconf.rb
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for fseeko()... yes
checking for ftello()... yes
checking for mkstemp()... no
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext
make  clean

current directory: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0.3.6/ext
make
generating zipruby-i386-mingw32.def
compiling mkstemp.c
mkstemp.c:51:0: warning: "S_ISDIR" redefined
c:\ruby193\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/sys/sta
t.h:68:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
compiling tmpfile.c
tmpfile.c: In function 'zipruby_tmpnam':
tmpfile.c:56:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcpy_s'
tmpfile.c:62:5: warning: implicit declaration of function '_sopen_s'
compiling zipruby.c
compiling zipruby_archive.c
zipruby_archive.c: In function 'zipruby_archive_get_name':
zipruby_archive.c:407:5: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3
 has type 'VALUE'
zipruby_archive.c: In function 'zipruby_archive_add_io':
zipruby_archive.c:701:81: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argume
nt 3 has type 'struct RString *'
zipruby_archive.c:717:78: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argume
nt 3 has type 'struct RString *'
zipruby_archive.c:726:47: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argume
nt 3 has type 'struct RString *'
zipruby_archive.c: In function 'zipruby_archive_replace_io':
zipruby_archive.c:780:97: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argume
nt 4 has type 'struct RString *'
zipruby_archive.c:789:66: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argume
nt 4 has type 'struct RString *'
zipruby_archive.c:796:66: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argume
nt 4 has type 'struct RString *'
zipruby_archive.c: In function 'zipruby_archive_read':
zipruby_archive.c:1447:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s'
zipruby_archive.c:1471:3: warning: implicit declaration of function '_fclose_nol
ock'
compiling zipruby_error.c
compiling zipruby_file.c
zipruby_file.c:13:14: warning: 'zipruby_file' declared 'static' but never define
d
compiling zipruby_stat.c
compiling zipruby_zip.c
compiling zipruby_zip_source_io.c
compiling zipruby_zip_source_proc.c
compiling zip_add.c
compiling zip_add_dir.c
compiling zip_close.c
zip_close.c: In function 'zip_close':
zip_close.c:146:29: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target
type
zip_close.c:153:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'
zip_close.c:188:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftello'
zip_close.c: In function 'copy_data':
zip_close.c:475:11: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expr
essions
zip_close.c:475:39: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression
compiling zip_crypt.c
zip_crypt.c:25:8: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
zip_crypt.c: In function 'zipenc_crc32':
zip_crypt.c:26:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'crc32' diff
er in signedness
c:\ruby193\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/zlib.h:
1285:23: note: expected 'const Bytef *' but argument is of type 'char *'
zip_crypt.c: In function 'init_keys':
zip_crypt.c:51:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expre
ssions
zip_crypt.c: In function 'decrypt_data':
zip_crypt.c:78:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expre
ssions
zip_crypt.c: In function 'copy_decrypt':
zip_crypt.c:98:3: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false

zip_crypt.c:109:28: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expr
essions
zip_crypt.c:109:28: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression
zip_crypt.c: In function 'encrypt_data':
zip_crypt.c:172:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expr
essions
zip_crypt.c: In function 'copy_encrypt':
zip_crypt.c:200:28: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expr
essions
zip_crypt.c:200:28: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression
zip_crypt.c: In function '_zip_crypt':
zip_crypt.c:265:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'
zip_crypt.c:293:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftello'
compiling zip_delete.c
compiling zip_dirent.c
zip_dirent.c: In function '_zip_cdir_write':
zip_dirent.c:109:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftello'
compiling zip_entry_free.c
compiling zip_entry_new.c
compiling zip_error.c
compiling zip_error_clear.c
compiling zip_error_get.c
compiling zip_error_get_sys_type.c
compiling zip_error_strerror.c
compiling zip_error_to_str.c
compiling zip_err_str.c
compiling zip_fclose.c
compiling zip_file_error_clear.c
compiling zip_file_error_get.c
compiling zip_file_get_offset.c
zip_file_get_offset.c: In function '_zip_file_get_offset':
zip_file_get_offset.c:64:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'
compiling zip_file_strerror.c
compiling zip_fopen.c
compiling zip_fopen_index.c
zip_fopen_index.c: In function '_zip_file_fillbuf':
zip_fopen_index.c:155:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'
compiling zip_fread.c
compiling zip_free.c
compiling zip_get_archive_comment.c
compiling zip_get_file_comment.c
compiling zip_get_name.c
compiling zip_get_num_files.c
compiling zip_memdup.c
compiling zip_name_locate.c
compiling zip_new.c
compiling zip_open.c
zip_open.c: In function 'zip_open':
zip_open.c:84:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'
zip_open.c:85:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftello'
compiling zip_rename.c
compiling zip_replace.c
compiling zip_set_archive_comment.c
compiling zip_set_file_comment.c
compiling zip_set_name.c
compiling zip_source_buffer.c
compiling zip_source_file.c
compiling zip_source_filep.c
zip_source_filep.c: In function 'read_file':
zip_source_filep.c:105:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'
zip_source_filep.c:115:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
zip_source_filep.c:115:38: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression
compiling zip_source_free.c
compiling zip_source_function.c
compiling zip_source_zip.c
zip_source_zip.c: In function 'read_zip':
zip_source_zip.c:132:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
zip_source_zip.c:132:44: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression
zip_source_zip.c:143:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
zip_source_zip.c:143:32: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression
compiling zip_stat.c
compiling zip_stat_index.c
compiling zip_stat_init.c
compiling zip_strerror.c
compiling zip_unchange.c
compiling zip_unchange_all.c
compiling zip_unchange_archive.c
compiling zip_unchange_data.c
linking shared-object zipruby.so
tmpfile.o: In function `zipruby_tmpnam':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/tmpfile.c:56: undefined reference to `strcpy_s'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/tmpfile.c:62: undefined reference to `_sopen_s'
zipruby_archive.o: In function `zipruby_archive_read':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zipruby_archive.c:1447: undefined reference to `fopen_s'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zipruby_archive.c:1471: undefined reference to `_fclose_nolock'
zip_close.o: In function `add_data':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:293: undefined reference to `ftello'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:312: undefined reference to `ftello'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:314: undefined reference to `fseeko'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:328: undefined reference to `fseeko'
zip_close.o: In function `zip_close':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:188: undefined reference to `ftello'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:153: undefined reference to `fseeko'
zip_crypt.o: In function `zip_crypt':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_crypt.c:293: undefined reference to `ftello'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_crypt.c:265: undefined reference to `fseeko'
zip_dirent.o: In function `zip_cdir_write':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_dirent.c:109: undefined reference to `ftello'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_dirent.c:116: undefined reference to `ftello'
zip_file_get_offset.o: In function `zip_file_get_offset':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_file_get_offset.c:64:undefined reference to `fseeko'
zip_fopen_index.o: In function `zip_file_fillbuf':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_fopen_index.c:155: undefined reference to `fseeko'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_fopen_index.c:155: undefined reference to `fseeko'
zip_open.o: In function `zip_checkcons':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:282: undefinedreference to `fseeko'
zip_open.o: In function `zip_open':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:84: undefined reference to `fseeko'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:85: undefined reference to `ftello'
zip_open.o: In function `zip_find_central_dir':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:436: undefinedreference to `fseeko'
zip_open.o: In function `zip_readcdir':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:217: undefinedreference to `fseeko'
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:220: undefinedreference to `ftello'
zip_source_filep.o: In function `read_file':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_source_filep.c:105: undefined reference to `fseeko'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [zipruby.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zipruby-0
.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/zi
pruby-0.3.6/gem_make.out
```

となり、やはりエラーとなります。

何方かインストールに成功されている方ご教授お願いします。

---

### 環境

- OS:Windows7 x86-64
- Ruby:1.9.3(mingw32)
- Development Kit:4.5.2

Comment: どうしても1.9でなければならない事情があるのでなければ、まずrubyをメンテナンスされているバージョンに更新してください。古いrubyというだけでいろいろな問題が発生しますので解決が難しくなります。

Comment: Linux版をWindowsに移植しております。Linux版がRuby1.9.3を使用しておりこのバージョンとなっております。また、ネットの情報の中には、Ruby 2系ではZipruby をインストール出来ないとの情報も目撃しております。最新のRubyでZipruby のインストールに成功した方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

あてずっぽうですが `gem install zipruby --platform mswin32` だとどうですか？